# Significant predictors of mpg in mtcars dataset in R

Tags: regression, stepwise-regression

Which variables are significant predictors of mpg in mtcars dataset. When I perform following regression:

```
> mod = lm(mpg~., mtcars)
> summary(mod)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4506 -1.6044 -0.1196  1.2193  4.6271 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) 12.30337   18.71788   0.657   0.5181  
cyl         -0.11144    1.04502  -0.107   0.9161  
disp         0.01334    0.01786   0.747   0.4635  
hp          -0.02148    0.02177  -0.987   0.3350  
drat         0.78711    1.63537   0.481   0.6353  
wt          -3.71530    1.89441  -1.961   0.0633 .
qsec         0.82104    0.73084   1.123   0.2739  
vs           0.31776    2.10451   0.151   0.8814  
am           2.52023    2.05665   1.225   0.2340  
gear         0.65541    1.49326   0.439   0.6652  
carb        -0.19942    0.82875  -0.241   0.8122  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.65 on 21 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.869,     Adjusted R-squared:  0.8066 
F-statistic: 13.93 on 10 and 21 DF,  p-value: 3.793e-07

> smod = step(mod)
....
....

> summary(smod)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + qsec + am, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4811 -1.5555 -0.7257  1.4110  4.6610 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   9.6178     6.9596   1.382 0.177915    
wt           -3.9165     0.7112  -5.507 6.95e-06 ***
qsec          1.2259     0.2887   4.247 0.000216 ***
am            2.9358     1.4109   2.081 0.046716 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.459 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8497,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8336 
F-statistic: 52.75 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 1.21e-11
```

But qsec is only weakly related to mpg:

[image]

Also many variables are highly correlated with each other. The number of rows is also only 32 with 11 variables. How should one find significant predictors of mpg in this dataset.

Comment: This is a home work in JHU's Coursera class.

Comment: I agree it is a self-study question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the original source of the data, that paper which mentioned it first. You'll see that the authors assembled the data set to show the methods of selection of variables! They'll demonstrate and compare several methods of model selection, just pick any you like and submit it as an answer.

Comment: Can you provide the link to original paper? I tried to search but could not find it, probably because mtcars example has been used everywhere.

Comment: @rnso there's a citation in the R page for `?mtcars`. Here's the paper: http://www.mortality.org/INdb/2008/02/12/8/document.pdf

Comment: Thanks. For such commonly cited datasets, there should be a page each on the best method and final conclusion on their analysis. The upvotes will decide on which method is the most acceptable method. IMHO.

Comment: There's no such a thing as a best model in statistics. The original paper describes the process of selection which makes this point even clearer.